# Git rebase/merge from master branch doesn't update all differences from current branch

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

I have to merge my collegue's branch into the master branch, but for some reason he has a lot of the new commits deleted. For example, a commit that adds an Example.py file in master branch, shows up in his branch as deleted Example.py. Hence, I want to merge master in his branch to add those deleted files. I tried rebasing and merging, but only a portion of those files come from master. The others are ignored for some reason. Does anyone have an idea what causes this?

Comment: What does "shows up in his branch as deleted" mean, specifically?  Please, instead of vague characterizations of what you're looking at, show what you're looking at.  The way to tell what differences Git's seeing is `git diff thisbranch...otherbranch` and `git diff otherbranch...thisbranch`, unless you've got an unusually complicated merge history that'll show you exactly what GIt's trying to merge.

Comment: jthill asks about it because this is not possible: "commit that adds an Example.py file in master branch, shows up in his branch as deleted Example.py." The same commit ID in two different branches cannot contain different changes. Maybe his branch simply doesn't have those specific commit IDs in his branch's history yet? Or, if his branch does have those commits, maybe some of his commits after it are incorrectly deleting the files?